# Detect button from previous activity

Tags: android, button, android-activity

I have an activity with various buttons, and they all lead to the same activity, the second activity should change its contents depending on which button was pressed.
Can I detect which button was pressed on a previous activity? How can I do that?

Thank you very much. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply pass a different parameter when you click on different buttons

```
//First button
btn1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() 
{
  @Override          
  public void onClick(View v) 
  {              
    Intent intent = new Intent();
    intent.setAction(this, SecondActivity.class);
    intent.putExtra("button", 1);
    startActivity(intent);  
  }
});

//Second button the same code but you change
intent.putExtra("button", 2);
```

And in the second Activity, you check the value:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
  Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
  if (extras != null) {
   int btnNumber = extras.getInt("button");
   switch(btnNumber) 
   {
     case 1 : ... ; break;
     case 2 : ... ; break;
   }
}
```

Comment: This answer is the right one. But don't use "button". Define a proper constant in the target (second activity). And give it more sense according to the second activity, not the first one. This will lead to less coupling and cleaner code.

Comment: great answer, I got it working, thank you. Although I used extras.getInt("Button") instead of getString.